# How can I close a rectangular PVC pipe without using glue?

Tags: pipe, pvc

I will use a rectangular pipe (65mmx100mm) for growing herbs on the wall outside my house.
I want to close both ends of a rectangular PVC pipe without using glue so I can pull at anytime both ends for cleaning purpose.

Does anyone has a good mechanical idea?
I'm trying to maintain the cost low so the less parts the better.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this really a duplicate question of your last question? There isn't any safety/health reason not to use the non-toxic glue we talked about in you last question.

Comment: No, I decided to not use glue so that I can clean the inside

Comment: There **are** caps available for these which will friction fit just like the caps for standard PVC pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your frequency of cleaning, you can put a bead of silicone around the outside after joining them. You can peel almost all of it off by hand to clean it.

Answer (score 1):

Cork/Foam/Anything that can be molded to fit the hole snuggly.

Also a they make  caps that extend slightly into the pvc pipe., find a rubber seal (old bike inner tube, large rubber band etc..)attach it to the cap, and then shove it in the hole.

Answer (score 1):

How closed do you need it to be?

You could drill 2-4 bolts through the side to make something of a fence.  It would contain dirt, but let water drain out.

Alternately, if there is a proper cap for this pipe, you could drill a single bolt through both the cap and pipe, and hold the cap in place with the bolt.